# Need Help Verifying This Complexity

Tags: c, complexity-theory, time-complexity

I'm working around with some complexity and this one I know is an easy one.  I need to know if the complexity I found for this algorithm is well done, if not could someone help me correct it please.

```
int algorithm(int x)
{
    int y=1;                                    1
    while(y<=x)                                 x+1
    {
        int z=x-y;                              x
        while(z>=1)                             x
        {
            z=z/5;                              x-1
        }
        y++;                                    x
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I found the complexity to be of order O(x).
Any Help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Just curious: does this algorith it anything useful. BTW it doesn't compile because there is no `return` statement.

Comment: It is just a random code I found and decided to find it's complexity, btw I just added a return 0;

Answer (score 2):

You have x iterations of main loop

> while(y<=x)

, and in each loop you have 0..log(x) iterations of internal loop

> while(z>=1)

So imho complexity is o(xlogx)

Comment: But **z** depends on x and **y**, while **y** variate after every iteration of the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

The preliminary form of your algorithm would look like the following:

[image]